# Scala Lift - Mongodb int field value becomes negative

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I have the following model:

```
class Recording private() extends MongoRecord[Recording] with ObjectIdPk[Recording] {

    def meta = Recording

    object time extends IntField(this)
    object fulltime extends IntField(this)

}
```

When I do the following:

```
var time = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
var fulltime = System.currentTimeMillis()

Recording.createRecord.
time(time.toInt).
fulltime(fulltime.toInt).
save
```

The field "time" is correctly stored as "1334919100", but the "fulltime" field is saved as "-815728745", whats going on here? Is there something I need to do for it to accept a timestamp in full milisecond length?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.currentTimeMillis` returns a `Long`. You are only lucky that it works in the `time` case. In `fulltime` you are experiencing an integer overflow. (This already happens in the `toInt` call.) Choose `LongField` for both objects.

Comment: Tried changing IntField(this) to LongField(this) but am still getting the negative value?

Comment: Do you still have the `toInt` in there?

Comment: Perfect, removed the .toInt and all works perfectly. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Yes. As I said, the overflow happens there. (I should have been a bit clearer about this, though.) If you’re using `LongField`s, there is no need to convert to `Int` anyway.